# Try to execute multiple test case with same browser instance

Tags: testng

/**** am trying to execute multiple test cases in different class but in same browser instance. But  I am facing the issue like second test suite are always try to open new window or session. But I want to open the same browser only rather than it took always new window. Please Help.****/

public class LoginPage extends BaseClass {

```
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Login & Signup')]")
    private WebElement LoginLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="(//form/div/input[@type='text'])")
    private WebElement UnTxBx;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='password']")
    private WebElement PwdTxBx;

    @FindBy(xpath="(//button[@type='submit'])[last()]")
    private WebElement loginBtn;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(text(),'Your username or password is incorrect')]")
    private WebElement invalidLoginMsg;


    //Intializing Page Object
    public LoginPage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public  FKartHome login(String username, String password)
    {

     //// LoginLink.click();
     // WaitStatementLib.eWaitForVisible(10, UnTxBx);
      UnTxBx.sendKeys(username);    
      PwdTxBx.sendKeys(password);
      loginBtn.click();
      return  new FKartHome();



    }

//This is my Login Page


public class FKartHome extends BaseClass {
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@title='Search for products, brands and more']")
    private WebElement SearchSendKeys;


    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@type='submit']")
    private WebElement ClickSubmit;


    public FKartHome()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }



    public  ItemsPage search(String searchBook)
    {
        WaitStatementLib.eWaitForVisible(20, SearchSendKeys);
        SearchSendKeys.sendKeys(searchBook);
        ClickSubmit.click();

        return new ItemsPage();
    }
```

// This is my HomePage

```
public class LoginPageTest extends BaseClass {
    public  static LoginPage  loginPage;
     public static FKartHome fKartHome;

    @Test
    public static void loginTest()
    {
        String filepath= "/home/ambrish/Lockdown_Tets/SeleniumPractice/TestDataSheet/testdata.xlsx";
        String username = ExcelUtilities.readData(filepath, "sheet1", 1, 1);
        //System.out.println(username);
        String password = ExcelUtilities.readData(filepath, "sheet1", 1, 2);
        //System.out.println(password);
        LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();
        //fKartHome=loginPage.login(username, password);
        lp.login(username, password);



    }
```

//  This is my 1st TestCase Class

```
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@title='Search for products, brands and more']")
    private WebElement SearchSendKeys;


    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@type='submit']")
    private WebElement ClickSubmit;


    public FKartHome()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }



    public  ItemsPage search(String searchBook)
    {
        WaitStatementLib.eWaitForVisible(20, SearchSendKeys);
        SearchSendKeys.sendKeys(searchBook);
        ClickSubmit.click();

        return new ItemsPage();
    }



}

//This is my 2nd TestClass
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: ***** <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" >
  <test name="Test">
   
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
  <parameter name="baseUrl" value="https://www.flipkart.com"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="scriptTest.LoginPageTest"/>
       <class name="scriptTest.FKartHomeTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite --> *****                                       This is testng.xml file